# Topological Vector Space and $\phi : X \to \mathbb{K}$ linear form such that $\phi$ is not continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

The following question was asked in my assignment of Functional Analysis course and unfortunately no question in  assignment was discussed by the professor.

> Question: Let $X$ be a topological vector space over $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{C}$ or $ \mathbb{R}$ and let $\phi: X\to \mathbb{K}$  be a linear form. Show that if $\phi$ is not continuous , then $\phi (W)  $ equals $\mathbb{K} $ for any neighbourhood W of 0 in X and deduce that $ker(\phi)$ is dense in $X$.

Let $\phi$ be not continuous. I am very sorry but I have no idea on how to prove the statement asked in the question. I am not able to find any proposition in class notes which I can use here. I couldn't find much of use in this particular question by googling.

I really don't know which result should be used. *Please don't vote to close this question!* Please guide me!

Comment: That's not a question. You have two distinct questions there.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I swear to god that they were part to same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, if $\phi$ is not continuous, then it is not continuous at $0$.

The following is a standard fact about topological vector spaces, and it is proven using the basic properties of its topology:

*The origin of a topological vector space admits a basis of balanced neighbourhoods*.

*We say that a set $X$ is balanced if $\alpha X\subset X$ for every $|\alpha|\leq 1$.

Now, take $W$ a neighbourhood of the origin. We can assume that it is balanced. Let $k\in \mathbb{K}$, $k\neq 0$.  Since $\phi$ is not continuous at $0$, $\phi(W)$ cannot be bounded (why?!), so we can find $x\in W$ such that $|\phi(x)|\geq |k|$. As $W$ is balanced, $(k/\phi(x))x\in W$, and $$ \phi\left( \frac{k}{\phi(x)}x\right)= k$$

So we get $\phi(W)=\mathbb{K}$, as wanted.

The second part is an immediate consequence of the first. For if we take any $x\in X$ and any neighbourhood $W$ of $x$, $W-x$ is a neighbourhood of $0$, and by what we have just proven, $\mathbb{K}=\phi(W-x)=\phi(x)+\phi(W-x)=\phi(W)$.

In particular, there is $y\in W$ with $\phi(y)=0$. This proves that $\operatorname{ker}(\phi)$ is dense in $X$.

Comment: "$\phi(W)$ cannot be bounded?" If it is bounded then it is continuous at 0 , which is a contradiction. Am I right?

Comment: How did you added $\phi(x)$ to $\phi(W-x)$ , how is that valid?

Comment: "there is y∈W with ϕ(y)=0," I understand this. But how does it proves that $ker(\phi)$ is dense in $X$?

Comment: @3ibfwcbi To your first question, yes, you’re right. It is easy to show that if there exists a neighbourhood of the origin whose image is bounded, then by linearity the map is continuous at $0$. 

For the second question, I can add $\phi(x)$ (and in fact, any constant I’d like) because $\mathbb{K}$ is invariant under addition of a constant. 

Regarding the last question, I proved that in any neighbourhood of any point of the space, I can find a point of the kernel, which is the definition of being dense.

Answer (score 1):

You might start out by showing that if $\phi$ is discontinuous, it is discontinuous at $0$.  Next, note that for any $s, t \in \mathbb K$ with $s \ne 0$,
$W$ contains a point $x$ with $\phi(x) = t$ iff $sW$ contains $sx$ with $\phi(sx) = st$.